# Creating a custom Toast android

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to create a custom Toast and display it when user answer a question. It's a True-False game where the user gets a question and have to answer, depending on right or wrong answer I use different toasts. I have the layout, From Android Developers page. But I keep getting error (NullPointerException).

here's the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:background="#DAAA"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/toastImageV"
           android:src="@drawable/correcticon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/toastTextV"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
```

And here's the Java code, It is in the onClick method.

```
private void checkAnswer(int ans) {

    try{
    if(ans == q.getAnswer()){


        LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toastImageV);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toastTextV);



        Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.correcticon);
        text.setText(answerLang[0]);

        t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.setView(layout);
        t.show();
        getNewTF();
    }
    else{
        LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toastImageV);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toastTextV);



        Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.wronganswer);
        text.setText(answerLang[1]);

        t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        t.setView(layout);
        t.show();
        getNewTF();
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The checkAnswer takes an Integer parameter.

Here's the logcat:

```
08-28 17:05:33.698: W/System.err(13594): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at com.boilingstocks.qdroid.TrueFalse.checkAnswer(TrueFalse.java:363)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at com.boilingstocks.qdroid.TrueFalse.onClick(TrueFalse.java:331)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 17:05:33.718: W/System.err(13594):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-28 17:05:33.728: W/System.err(13594):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-28 17:05:33.728: W/System.err(13594):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Without the error and the corresponding line, we can't help much.

Comment: inflator root should be NULL, remove [(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root)] from the inflators and replace it with null value

Comment: I'm trying that too.. Still same error..

Comment: Which line is line 363 in your code?

Comment: try replacing `View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));` with `View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root), true);`. If that does not work flip `true` to `false`

Comment: In line 363, I have : img.setImageResource(R.drawable.correcticon);

Answer (score 0):

Its not able to recognize the ids, find id from View itself , try to use following code

```
View layout = inf.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastImageV);
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastTextV);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it!

I had to create the declare the toast with

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(Context, text, duration));
```

instead of ......

```
Toast t = Toast(getApplicationContext()), like described on Android...(?)
```

Thanks
Cheers! :)